# How to skip the initialization when copying objects in python?

Tags: python, initialization, copy-constructor

I want to implement my own copy method for a class A which looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.field1 = generate_a_list_of_ints()
    def __copy__(self):
        result = A()
        result.fiel1[:] = self.field1[:]
        return result
```

The problem with the code above is that when copying an A object, the initialization code will be invoked even though there is no need to get the initial values.

How can I copy the field1 without running initialization code? I looked for information about `__new__` but most of it was referring to factories and stuff that seemed unrelated, so it's still unclear to me how to skip the initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest an optional argument in your `__init__()` method, like so:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, init=True):
        if init:
            self.field1 = generate_a_list_of_ints()
    def __copy__(self):
        result = A(init=False)
        result.fiel1[:] = self.field1[:]
        return result
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Thank you. I'll wait some more time before accepting, just in case.